# I want to write a code that accepts numbers as a string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a code that accepts numbers as a string and a string of maths operators, then it should separate the string of numbers putting a maths operator (both entered by the user) in between and prints the answer of the calculation.
i.e. user inputs: "2468" and "+++" the code should produce 20 from (2+4+6+8).

Comment: What is your question? Was there any problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: if the numeric string is of length n, is the string of binary operators of length n - 1?

Comment: assuming binary operator is n-1 if length of string is n,

Comment: sorry i forgot to add my code that doesnt work.

Comment: Please edit your question with code that you tried to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code

```py
nums = input('Enter a list of comma separated numbers : ')
ops = input('Enter a list of operations : ')
nums = [i.strip() for i in nums.split(',')]
ops = [i for i in ops]
if len(ops) != len(nums) - 1:
    raise ValueError('operations must be length 1 less than numbers')

def evaluate(nums, ops):
    op = [nums[i]+ops[i] for i in range(len(ops))] + [nums[-1]]
    op = ''.join(op)
    return eval(op)

print(evaluate(nums, ops))
```

Sample output

```py
Enter a list of comma separated numbers : 1,2,3,4
Enter a list of operations : +++
10

Enter a list of comma separated numbers : 1, 3, 5, 7
Enter a list of operations : *++
15
```